# Azure Data Factory Copy Failure on DB2

Tags: azure, db2, azure-data-factory, ibm-midrange, sqldatatypes

I need to do a full extract (SELECT * FROM) on i series DB2 database.
I am using Copy Activity which fails on the source extract due to special character encodings:

> Error code 2200
>
> Failure type User configuration issue
>
> Details Failure happened on 'Source' side.
> ErrorCode=DB2DriverRunFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=Error
> thrown from driver. Sql code:
> '-343',Source=Microsoft.DataTransfer.ClientLibrary.Db2Connector,''Type=Microsoft.HostIntegration.DrdaClient.DrdaException,Message=HISMPCB0001
> In BasePrimitiveConverter an exception has occurred. Exception
> description: Output buffer is smaller than required size 12
> SQLSTATE=HY000
> SQLCODE=-343,Source=Microsoft.HostIntegration.Drda.Requester,'

I've researched similar issues here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/467456/failure-happened-source-side-in-copy-activity-for.html

I believe that the source of the issue is native ADF connector's data-type mapping for DB2: DB2 data types are converted to interim data types used internally within the service when loading into the sink. These interim data types seem to be incompatible, causing failure at the source:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-db2?tabs=data-factory#data-type-mapping-for-db2

I've tried the following unsuccessfully:

1. Adding fault tolerance to skip incompatible rows
2. Changing datatypes for incompatible columns

Playing around with datatyping on ingest query works for some columns, but not others -- it is an inconsistent solution, looking for advice on how fix this and keep full source query as is.

Answer (score 0):

With this given information it is unclear what part of data actually causing the issue. The issue could be from a column or some values in the column.

The following data type conversions are supported between the interim types from source to sink.

[image]

I suggest you if you have a support plan you may file a support ticket, else could you please send an email to azcommunity@microsoft.com. Provide the Subscription ID and sample data so that they can provide the exact solution.

Comment: Has someone placed the ticket with Azure Support?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enable the fault tolerance data type, looks this issue of characters no allowed in the azure db:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/copy-activity-fault-tolerance

So i recommed execute a disctinct in your table and check if you have a different data in some row before to move the copy.